# Public Variable returns undefined in Private Method

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a very simple piece of code, and my question is: why is the variable `this.wheels` undefined in the `getWheel()` private method? I did solved it by passing the context as a parameter in the call inside the public `this.spinWheel()` method (writing `getWheel.call(this, wheelNumber)`), but it was just I shot after read an article, I wasn't really sure what I was doing because the article wasn't that good.

I know it's something with the function getting the wrong context, but I just can't get the grasp of it (why isn't it getting the right context, if the private function is inside `Car`?). Can somebody explain in detail or provide a good resource to read?

**JavaScript**:

```
Car = function () {

    this.wheels = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    function getWheel (wheel) {
        this.wheels.some(function (element, index, array) {
            if (element == wheel) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Wheel " + element + ": vruuum!";
            }
        });
    };

    this.spinWheel = function (wheelNumber) {
        getWheel(wheelNumber);
    };

};

var myCar = new Car();

myCar.spinWheel();
```

The code is [in this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Krs/3/).

Any other advice would be welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you don't call it on the right context.

If you add

```
console.log(this)
```

at the start of `getWheel`, you'll see that `this` is `window`, the global default context in non strict mode.

A solution would be to change

```
this.spinWheel = function (wheelNumber) {
    getWheel(wheelNumber);
};
```

to

```
this.spinWheel = function (wheelNumber) {
    getWheel.call(this, wheelNumber);
};
```

You could also declare in the constructor a variable holding `this` and use it directly, or store `this.wheels` in a private variable.

Comment: I get the solution, but why is the `getWheel()` method inside `this.spinWheel()` being called on `window`? Do I have to use this .call() method to all private methods inside a class to ensure they're called in the right context?

Comment: @rockleegustavo There's no implicit `this` in JavaScript property access, you have to provide it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought because the `getWheel()` method was inside the `Car` function it would always be called in the right context, but now I realize it's not that simple. I'll read more about context when functions are called. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dystroy's solution, you could declare wheels as a `var`. Note the small change to `getWheel` too.

```
Car = function () {

    var wheels = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    function getWheel (wheel) {
        wheels.some(function (element, index, array) {
            if (element == wheel) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Wheel " + element + ": vruuum!";
            }
        });
    };

    this.spinWheel = function (wheelNumber) {
        getWheel(wheelNumber);
    };

};
```